# Is it bad practice to use tkinter variable classes as class attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

As you can see from my code I'm subclassing tk.Frame to create a custom widget for a tkinter gui.  I'll be instantiating this class in a main gui, and will need to change the values of the labels in it periodically.  If I use the tkinter variable class StringVar() I'll need to use it's .set() method to change the values of the labels referencing them.

Is this bad practice?  What I mean is if someone besides myself were to use this custom widget, they would have to know to use the .set() method to pass in a new value.  Something about this doesn't feel right to me...maybe I'm overthinking it.  Thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk

class CurrentTempFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=200, height=120,
                 background_color='black',
                 font_color='white',
                 font = 'Roboto'):

    # Call the constructor from the inherited class
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, width=width, height=height,
                      bg=background_color)

    # Class variables - content
    self.temperature_type = tk.StringVar()
    self.temperature_type.set('Temperature')
    self.temperature_value = tk.StringVar()
    self.temperature_value.set('-15')
    self.temperature_units = tk.StringVar()
    self.temperature_units.set('°F')


    self.grid_propagate(False)           # disables resizing of frame
    #self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    #self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    title_label = tk.Label(self,
                           textvariable=self.temperature_type,
                           font=(font, -20),
                           bg=background_color,
                           fg=font_color)

    value_label = tk.Label(self,
                           textvariable=self.temperature_value,
                           font=(font, -80),
                           bg=background_color,
                           fg=font_color)

    units_label = tk.Label(self,
                           textvariable=self.temperature_units,
                           font=(font, -50),
                           bg=background_color,
                           fg=font_color)

    title_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    value_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    units_label.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='N')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    current_temp = CurrentTempFrame(root, font_color='blue')
    current_temp.temperature_value.set('100')
    current_temp.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='NW')
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this bad practice? What I mean is if someone besides myself were to use this custom widget, they would have to know to use the .set() method to pass in a new value. [...].

What your doing is not bad practice. It is perfectly acceptable to make an instance variable of a class, be an instance of another class. It makes no difference that the class instance is from `tkinter`.

*However*, if other people will be using your class, you *should* document it. Give the class and all of its public methods doc-strings. In the class, clearly document the type of each instance variable, and what their purpose is. Do the same for methods. Document what the method is for, and the correct usage.

In other words, document your classes API. Make sure it's clear and concise, and can be understood by other people. This is how you can be sure future users of your class - including yourself - can understand what your class is for, and how it should be used.

Comment: Thank you Christian, that makes sense, I appreciate it.  Now to learn more about doc-strings!

Comment: Sure thing @Mike, glad to help. [Here is a good resource related to documenting python code](http://blog.dolphm.com/pep257-good-python-docstrings-by-example/) to help get you started.